# Spotfire IronPython - Calculated value from data table?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I want to use IronPython scripts in Spotfire to do calculated values from specific columns in data tables, i.e. calculate the Sum([cost]) for the previous week, and then print it in the output console (getting to this stage will let me fulfill my purpose, which is to add this calculated numeric value to an email).

Any ideas on how to proceed? I am trying to refer to the column and then retrieving the values in the row collection, but after that; how can I do some aggregations, and limit the data by a timeframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add script parameters to your python code:

[image]

[image]

It has all the abilities of a calculated column to limit data and write your own expression.

Comment: Awesome! And I can refer to any table, as in Sum([table].[column])? Any quick idea on how to incorporate a date conditional with this? (i.e. sum up cost for last week)

Comment: This should do the trick, Sum(If([table].[date]>XXXXXXX,[table].[value],0))

Comment: You can also reference this page for date limiting expressions. https://spotfired.blogspot.com/2014/09/last-week-month-date-expressions.html